# CSS responsive layout with diagonal shapes

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm developing this site to be a one-page scrollable site where each section is a diagonal shape.  Is there a way to make this more responsive where, regardless of what the screen size is, when someone sees the home page they can see the little peach triangle on the lower right corner with the word "Our Work" in it? Also, if there is a better way to set up this page, I welcome any suggestions.

http://bit.ly/1jwn41m

The CSS and HTML can be viewed in "View Source"

```
       <div id="logo" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
            <h1><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.png"/></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            <h4>inspiring people to take the leap and make their ideas happen</h4>
            <div id="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <section id="portfolio" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
            <h3 id="work">Our Work</h3>
     </secion>
      <section id="contact">
      <h3 id="touch">Get in Touch</h3>
            <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="9" title="Contact form 1"]' ); ?>
      </section>

            <div id="shapes">
                <div id="design-shape"></div>   
                <div id="contact-shape"></div>  

            </div>
```

---

CSS

```
#logo {
height: auto;
width: 1000px;
text-align: center;
margin: 100px auto;
z-index: 15;
margin-top: 100px;
}
#logo img {
text-align: center;
}

#shapes {
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

 #design-shape {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e98e82;
 position: absolute;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 height: 1040px;
 top: 1200px;
 left:50%;
 width: 5000px;
 margin-left: -2500px;
 z-index: 6;
 }

 #contact-shape {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
 position: absolute;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
 height: 1460px;
 top: 2757px;
 left:50%;
 width: 5000px;
 margin-left: -2500px;
 z-index: 1;
 }

 #portfolio {
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -210px;
     margin-top: -60px;
 width: 800px;
 z-index: 8;
 overflow: auto;
 }

 #contact {
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 z-index: 9;
 width: 800px;
 margin-left: 276px;
     margin-top: 580px;
}
```

Comment: This was probably downvoted (not by me) because the question does not contain enough information to diagnose the problem. Linking to a page, that will change, will render this question and answers useless to future visitors. Could you please add a _simple_ demonstration of the problem and put all relevant code in the question? Also, since this is quite design specific an image showing what the problem is and what you want instead would be very helpful.

Comment: I updated it- thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to make a definition for *responsive* that suits everybody expectations.

In your case, it's easy to adapt to dimensions changes, but not to ratio changes.

Anyway, one approach could be the following, using vh units for positioning (with this technique, you won't be able to support IE8, and Safari is buggy)

HTML

```
<div class="test">OUR WORK</div>
<div class="diagonal"></div>
```

CSS

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90vh;
    width: 98%;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.diagonal {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90vh;
    width: 98%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 80% 0px;
    transform: skewY(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 80% 0px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GsRs/)

Comment: Thank you! But, I'm hesitant to use a solution that isn't supported by IE.

Comment: Well, you weren't supporting IE8 anyway (because of transforms), so your only concern is Safari. I can't tell you exactly what *buggy* means, (I am taking it from http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) may be you can try and see what happens.